# Для GIMP + BLENDER не работает сокращение Ctrl-Alt-O

Tags: linux, клавиатура, fedora

Извиняюсь, несли не по теме, но не знаю кого спросить.

**Итак, Федора 64 бит, 28 версия.**

Для ГИМПа на работает клавиатурное сокращение Ctrl-Alt-O (открыть изображение как новый слой). 
Для Блендера Ctrl-Alt-O сокращение "связать файл"

Сама функция в меню работает. Если назначить другое сокращение — оно работает, а Ctrl-Alt-O нет.

Смотрел системные настройки XFCE-4, может эта комбинация используется системой — но ничего так и не нашёл. 
В общем я озадачен. Если система перебивает эту комбинацию, то подобное может всплыть и в других программах.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, нашёл причину. Это программа Clipit. Она и многие другие клавиши блокирует "под себя".

```
<Ctrl><Alt>H
<Ctrl><Alt>A
<Ctrl><Alt>P
<Ctrl><Alt>F
<Ctrl><Alt>O
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]